# Alternatives for Account Management in FileZilla Server

Tags: ftp, filezilla

For our FTP server, my company has installed FileZilla Server version 0.9.41 beta. The server is working well and we're pleased with it. My question involves account management - FileZilla Server includes an easy-to-use UI for managing user accounts, but I would prefer to handle user accounts with the rest of our customer info, like logins for the company website, notes of the last support issue, and so on. I don't see a way to configure FileZilla Server to accept a different account manager. Is there a plugin architecture that I can code against, or better, modules that I can install that would give me the flexibility I'm looking for? Ideally, I'd be able to configure FileZilla Server with a SQL connection string and CRUD queries, and then manage the account store myself.

Answer (score 1):

There is a XML file called "FileZilla Server.xml" in your program directory. In this file you can edit all relevant options regarding settings and user management of the server.

Don't forget to reload the config with "/reload-config" afterwards.

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by `/reload-config`?

Comment: Ah, Google.... https://wiki.filezilla-project.org/Command-line_arguments_%28Server%29